Is there a way to limit the amount of bytes downloaded from a FirebaseStorage file
I am making an app that has the feature of listening to audio from others. It has a recorder so people can submit their audio.
On the homepage, I would like to have a widget where only a portion of an audio file is played, say 10% of an audio file from Firebase Storage.
Here is my approach:
        onTap: () async {
          portionaudio = await FirebaseStorage.instance
              .refFromURL(widget.urlaudio)
              .getData(50000);




          theAudiosample.setSourceBytes(portionaudio!);
          theAudiosample.play(theAudiosample.source!);
        });
  }

So, the portionaudio variable stores the bytes obtained by a function provided by FirebaseStorage. I tried to use the getData function to limit the amount of data but now that I read the description, it says it will cancel the operation once the limit established is reached (50000 bytes in this case), so it didn't work.
One approach I was thinking about is to create two collections, one that stores the 10% samples of recorded audio, and another collection to store the complete audio file in a different collection. Record the audio in chunks, but I think that approach is going to complicate things.
The reason I want to add a feature that does not consume a lot of data, and saves costs.
So is there a simple way to do it? I am using Flutter and Firestore.


I tried to use the getData function to limit the amount of data but now that I read the description, it says it will cancel the operation once the limit established is reached (50000 bytes in this case), so it didn't work.

This is what the getData() function does. The argument that you're passing actually represents the maximum amount of bytes to download. And yes, right after you download the specified amount of bytes, the process stops. It does not continue to download the remaining bytes. This function is present to protect against memory issues.

One approach I was thinking about is to create two collections, one that stores the 10% samples of recorded audio, and another collection to stores the complete audio file in a different collection.

That's a quite common approach. So you can store a sample, as you already said, 10% from the entire audio file, and play the entire file only on demand.

Record the audio in chunks, but I think that approach is going to complicate things.

That's not as complicated as you might think. This approach of loading an audio file in smaller chunks is widely used, and is also called "audio pagination". So I definitely recommend this approach.
